# Got stuck proving that covariance matrices are positive definite

Tags: probability, covariance

I got stuck trying to understand the proof of the following statement:

> Statement: The covariance matrix $C=\text{Cov}_X$ of a random vector $X$ is positive definite, that is $$\sum_{i,j}^dC_{ij}z_iz_j \geq 0, \ \text{for all } (z_1,z_2, \dots, z_d) \in \mathbb{R}^d.$$
>   Proof: Set $Y=\sum_{i=1}^d  \{  z_i (X_i-EX_i) \} $ for $(z_1, \dots, z_d) \in \mathbb{R}^d$. Then $$0 \leq EY^2 =  E\sum_{i,j} \{ z_i z_j (X_i-EX_i ) (X_j -EX_j) \}$$
>   $$=\sum_{i,j} \{ z_i z_j E \{ (X_i-EX_i)(X_j-EX_j) \}\} = \sum_{i,j} C_{ij}z_iz_j,$$
>   where by definition of the covariance matrix
>   $$C_{ij}=E \{ (X_i-EX_i)(X_j-EX_j)\}.$$

So, the part I don't understand is the following equality $\rightarrow$
$$EY^2 =  E\sum_{i,j} \{ z_i z_j (X_i-EX_i ) (X_j -EX_j) \}.$$

Because, when I try to work on the LFH of the previous equality, I get:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
EY^2 & =E \left(  \sum_{i=1}^d  \{  z_i (X_i-EX_i) \} \right)^2 \\
& = E \left(  \sum_{i=1}^d  \{  z_i^2 (X_i-EX_i)^2 \} + \sum_{i,j=1}^d \{ z_i z_j   (X_i-EX_i ) (X_j -EX_j) \} \right) \\
& =  \sum_{i=1}^d    z_i^2 E(X_i-EX_i)^2  + E\sum_{i,j=1}^d \{ z_i z_j   (X_i-EX_i ) (X_j -EX_j) \}  \\
& \geq E\sum_{i,j=1}^d \{ z_i z_j   (X_i-EX_i ) (X_j -EX_j) \}  \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second line of your work, you split the sum into $i=j$ and $i\neq j$ pieces; this is often a useful technique.  But then you treat the $i\neq j$ part 
as 
$$\sum_{i,j=1}^d \{ z_i z_j (X_i-EX_i ) (X_j -EX_j) \}
$$ instead of 
$$\sum_{i\neq j} \{ z_i z_j (X_i-EX_i ) (X_j -EX_j) \} $$

The difference of the two expressions is precisely what you are off by in the third line, namely, you have double counted 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^d z_i^2 E(X_i-EX_i)^2 $$